# Image, matrix as a txt

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a homework about an image. I have to convert it to text as Digital Number of Image. Then I'll find the minimum value in this text, and subtractions all values with min value. I need help if possible.

Comment: Please provide code example of what have you tried so far.

Comment: To add to basia's to-the-point comment, also consider adding a small example to make it clear what your intended output is (and the code *you've tried* that doesn't get you that). At the moment, I can think of several different things. [Be specific](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Actually I couldn't write any code about that. I tried. As I said, I have to take DN ( Digital Number of a image) and I have to find minimum value first. then I have to subtractions min value with all values. Then I have to change back it to an image.